# How to query the most recent entry using group_by on a jsonb field attribute

Tags: postgresql, group-by, elixir, ecto

Given a schema (I'm using Ecto) that look roughly like this:

- A `User` has many `:nodes`
- A `Node` has many `:versions`

I want to create a query that will return a users most recent version of all nodes, ordered by the version insert time.

The relationship between `User` and `Node` uses Ecto's `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations. Unfortunately the `Version` schema is weird one and the relationship to the node is made on a nested attribute in a jsonb field (I can't change this).

The best I have so far is:

```
grouping = Version
|> select([g], %{node_id: fragment("data->'node'->>'id'"), inserted_at: max(g.inserted_at)})
|> group_by([g], g.node_id)

Version
|> join(:inner, [v], g in subquery(grouping), on: fragment("data->'node'->>'id'") == g.node_id)
|> join(:inner, [v], n in Node, on: fragment("data->'node'->>'id'") == n.id)
|> where([_v, _g, n], n.user_id == ^user_id)
|> order_by([v], desc: :inserted_at)
|> Repo.all
```

When I run the query I get this error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column st0.node_id does not exist

query:
  SELECT t0."guid", t0."state", t0."channel", t0."tags", t0."data", t0."meta", t0."inserted_at", t0."updated_at" FROM "versions" AS t0
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT data->'node'->>'node_id' AS "node_id", max(st0."inserted_at") AS "inserted_at" FROM "versions" AS st0 GROUP BY st0."node_id") AS s1
    ON data->'node'->>'node_id' = s1."node_id"
  INNER JOIN "nodes" AS n2 ON data->'node'->>'node_id' = n2."id"
  WHERE (n2."user_id" = $1)
  ORDER BY t0."inserted_at" DESC
```

I feel I'm not a million miles away here but clearly I'm doing something wrong. If someone is able to point out what I should be doing in plain SQL I'll be able to translate that to Ecto.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is rather unclear what the structure of your data is.

Comment: I only read this for 2 minutes but if you are OK talking about raw SQL, the problem seems to be this line: `SELECT data->'node'->>'node_id' AS "node_id", max(st0."inserted_at") AS "inserted_at" FROM "versions" AS st0 GROUP BY st0."node_id") AS s1`. It should be `SELECT data->'node'->>'node_id' AS "node_id", max(st0."inserted_at") AS "inserted_at" FROM "versions" AS st0 GROUP BY "node_id") AS s1` (I think). I hope this is legible in a comment.

Comment: @PeacefulJames yes that has helped thank you. It moved me on and helped me realise another issue with the query. I'll post an answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Have solved my own question, will share here.

Firstly a comment from @PeacefulJames revealed an SQL error in the way Ecto composed the `GROUP BY` part of the query. I could resolve this by using `group_by(fragment("node_id"))`.

This allowed me to see the query was wrong anyway and [this article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ordering-within-a-sql-group-by-clause) helped point me in the right direction.

The following query gives me the results I wanted.

```
SELECT t1."guid", t1."state", t1."channel", t1."tags", t1."data", t1."meta", t1."inserted_at", t1."updated_at"
  FROM (
    SELECT st0.data->'node'->>'node_id' AS "node_id", max(st0."inserted_at") AS "inserted_at"
    FROM "versions" AS st0
    GROUP BY node_id
  ) AS s0
  INNER JOIN "versions" AS t1
    ON (t1.data->'node'->>'node_id' = s0."node_id")
    AND (t1."inserted_at" = s0."inserted_at")
  INNER JOIN "nodes" AS n2
    ON t1.data->'node'->>'node_id' = n2."id"
  WHERE (n2."user_id" = $1)
  ORDER BY t1."inserted_at" DESC
```

Pulled off in Ecto with the following code:

```
grouping = Version
|> select([v], %{address: fragment("?.data->'node'->>'node_id'", v), inserted_at: max(v.inserted_at)})
|> group_by(fragment("node_id"))

subquery(grouping)
|> join(:inner, [g], v in Version, on: fragment("?.data->'node'->>'node_id'", v) == g.node_id and v.inserted_at == g.inserted_at)
|> join(:inner, [_g, v], n in Node, on: fragment("?.data->'node'->>'node_id'", v) == n.id)
|> where([_g, _v, n], n.user_id == ^user_id)
|> order_by([_g, v], desc: v.inserted_at)
|> select([_g, v], v)
|> Repo.all
```